# Symfony2 create and download zip file

Tags: php, symfony, zip

I have one application that upload some files and then I can compress as zip file and download.

The export action:

```
public function exportAction() {
        $files = array();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $doc = $em->getRepository('AdminDocumentBundle:Document')->findAll();
        foreach ($_POST as $p) {
            foreach ($doc as $d) {
                if ($d->getId() == $p) {
                    array_push($files, "../web/".$d->getWebPath());
                }
            }
        }
        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $zipName = 'Documents-'.time().".zip";
        $zip->open($zipName,  \ZipArchive::CREATE);
        foreach ($files as $f) {
            $zip->addFromString(basename($f),  file_get_contents($f)); 
        }

        $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(readfile("../web/".$zipName));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    $response->header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=../web/"'.$zipName.'"');
    $response->header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("../web/" . $zipName));
    $response->readfile("../web/" . $zipName);
    return $response;
    }
```

everything is ok until the line header.
and everytime I'm going here I got the error: "Warning: readfile(../web/Documents-1385648213.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

What is wrong?

and why when I upload the files, this files have root permissions, and the same happens for the zip file that I create.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

solved:

```
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zipName . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipName));
readfile($zipName);
```

apparently closing the file is important ;)

Comment: Controller needs to return a response. Last line should be ```return new Response(readfile($zipName));```

Comment: readfile() does not return a string which can be put into a response. You need to use a streaming response for that or use file_get_contents

Answer (score 26):

SYMFONY 3 - 4 example :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
* Create and download some zip documents.
*
* @param array $documents
* @return Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
*/
public function zipDownloadDocumentsAction(array $documents)
{
    $files = [];
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    foreach ($documents as $document) {
        array_push($files, '../web/' . $document->getWebPath());
    }

    // Create new Zip Archive.
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();

    // The name of the Zip documents.
    $zipName = 'Documents.zip';

    $zip->open($zipName,  \ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($file),  file_get_contents($file));
    }
    $zip->close();

    $response = new Response(file_get_contents($zipName));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="' . $zipName . '"');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($zipName));

    @unlink($zipName);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: We can use `$zip->addFile($thumbnailsPath, basename($thumbnailsPath));` instead of `$zip->addFromString(basename($file),  file_get_contents($file));`.

Comment: If using this answer you have problems with Windows not being able to open the generated "zip", check if `filesize` is working, if not try using `strlen` with the `file_get_contents` data.

Also, if you are gonna echo/var_dump something use `ob_end_clean` before reading the content of the file and returning it.

Answer (score 2):

Since **Symfony 3.2+** can use [file helper](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-file-controller-helper) to let file download in browser:

```
public function someAction()
{
    // create zip file
    $zip = ...;

    $this->file($zip);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ZipArchive creates the zip file into the root directory of your website if only a name is indicated into `open` function like `$zip->open("document.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE)`. Specify the path into this function like `$zip->open("my/path/document.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE)`. Do not forget delete this file with `unlink()` (see [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.unlink.php)).

Here you have an example in Symfony 4 (may work on earlier version):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use \ZipArchive;

public function exportAction()
{
    // Do your stuff with $files
    
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip_name = "../web/zipFileName.zip"; // Users should not have access to the web folder (it is for temporary files)
    // Create a zip file in tmp/zipFileName.zip (overwrite if exists)
    if ($zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
           
         // Add your files into zip
         foreach ($files as $f) {
            $zip->addFromString(basename($f),  file_get_contents($f)); 
         }          
         $zip->close();
    
         $response = new Response(
            file_get_contents($zip_name),
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            ['Content-Type' => 'application/zip', 
             'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($zip_name) . '"',
             'Content-Length' => filesize($zip_name)]);

         unlink($zip_name); // Delete file

         return $response;
     } else {
            // Throw an exception or manage the error
     }
}
```

You may need to add `"ext-zip": "*"` into your Composer file to use `ZipArchive` and `extension=zip.so` in your `php.ini`.

Answser inspired by [Create a Response object with zip file in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661903/create-a-response-object-with-zip-file-in-symfony/64661904).

Answer (score 0):

I think its better that you use

```
$zipFilesIds = $request->request->get('zipFiles')
foreach($zipFilesIds as $zipFilesId){
  //your vérification here 
}
```

with the post variable of your id of zip = 'zipFiles'. Its better of fetching all $_POST variables.

Answer (score 0):

To complete vincent response, just add this right before returning response :

```
...
$response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($zipName));

unlink($zipName);

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Work for me. Where $archive_file_name = 'your_path_to_file_from_root/filename.zip'.

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, \ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | \ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
  foreach ($files_data as $file_data) {

    $fileUri = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($file_data['file_url']);
    $filename = $file_data['folder'] . $file_data['filename'];
    $zip->addFile($fileUri, $filename);
  }
  $zip->close();
}


$response = new Response();

$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/zip');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($archive_file_name) . '"');
$response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($archive_file_name));

// Send headers before outputting anything.
$response->sendHeaders();
$response->setContent(readfile($archive_file_name));
return $response;
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained which lines you applied and why did you apply it.

Comment: Yes, please explain what you have changed in the code and why, e.g. by adding a link to the PHP documentation etc.